# How to set MimeType when archiving a file to AWS S3 in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3, jenkins-plugins

I meet an issue when archiving and downloading file to/from AWS S3 by artifact-manager-s3-plugin.

Question:
how to set a file’s content type before it was uploaded to aws s3

Backgroud:
my artifacts are .spk files and Jenkins recognize their content type as “application/zip” (it’s right, they really are zip files). When i click the artifacts’ link in job page, downloaded file will be auto renamed from xxx.spk to xxx.zip. It’s same with what happens when I try to download it from AWS Console.

I want to find a way that user can download artifacts from jenkins job page with their origin name.

Comment: archiveArtifacts "**/*.spk" is the function i used in jenkinsfile